# React Native Android - init fails

Tags: android, node.js, npm, react-native

I am attempting to create a new React Native project for Android. I followed the instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-setup) but when I attempt to init a new project using the command 
`react-native init TestProject`

I get the following error

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in D:\dev\projects\TestProject
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:477:11)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Not sure where to get more information about the error. I have Node v4, NPM v2.14. Another thing to note is that the folder that gets created has a package.json that references `node_modules/react-native/packager` which does not exist in the current directory or the global scope.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (comment by programmer123) I have been able to get my windows development box, up and running with the latest version of RN and NPM. I had this exact issue with the older versions of RN. Can you try this with the latest version of RN?

Answer (score 2):

I try it too and I met the same problem. Then I found this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2681

As said in the [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content): `OS X - Only OS X is currently supported`, and I'm using Windows which cause the issue.

I notice the path: `D:\dev\projects\TestProject\events.js`, so you are using Windows too.

Answer (score 2):

It's a platform issue. Only OSX is supported see [Issue and possible workarounds](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2681)

Answer (score 0):

```
react-native start
```

in cmd solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem but got the similar issue while running react-native project in windows.

The following worked for me (in windows). Not sure whether it will work in every scenario or not. Just give it a try.

1. Go to project location
2. run command: `react-native start`.
3. then in another cmd window run this command: `react-native run-android`.

Please comment below if doesn't work because I am still trying to figure out the reason.